# Virtual Office Whiteboard

Tags: windows, osx

So due to COVID my workplace has like many been working from home. We are a small company of less than 10 and are planning to not return to office as it is just additional costs.
I am looking for a tool/site that will allow us to have essentially an office whiteboard that will allow us to stick notes, images, and such onto in one place for us all to collaborate. Does such a thing exist? Almost as if windows sticky notes could be shared among multiple computers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Jamboard. It is a cloud-based app. That enables visual collaboration between users in real-time. Before the run and have every employer add Jamboard to their devices. It limit for 20 people. You can do all of the things above mentioned. It capable for Android and iOS.
Google Jamboard alternatives are Microsoft whiteboard, Explain Everything, Nimbus, Goodnotes 5, Loom, Dropbox paper, Evernote.
And also you can use these software,

1. Miro
2. MURAL
3. Limnu
4. Conceptboard